# Errors were encountered while processing: postfix E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: package-management, dpkg, postfix, 21.04

After updating Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 to 21.04, i am facing this issue, neither able to install nor to uninstall packages.

````
[sudo] password for commaderwolfer: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version (1:2.32.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up postfix (3.5.6-1) ...

Postfix (main.cf) configuration was not changed.  If you need to make changes, 
edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix 
configuration values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'systemctl reload postfix'.

Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: CommanderWolfer..
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: CommanderWolfer..
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 installed postfix package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 75
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```

after running sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up postfix (3.5.6-1) ...

Postfix (main.cf) configuration was not changed.  If you need to make changes, 
edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix 
configuration values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'systemctl reload postfix'.

Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: CommanderWolfer..
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: CommanderWolfer..
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 installed postfix package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 75
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
````

Comment: It looks like your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file has an error - similar to this one: [How to fix a postfix myhosting config problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612459/how-to-fix-a-postfix-myhosting-config-problem). You will need to edit the file and fix the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The error message above might be due to a corrupt dpkg database or a corrupt package (postfix). Use the following commands to resolve. Open up a terminal to execute the commands.

Reconfigure the dpkg database use the command

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Fix the broken packages

```
sudo apt install--fix-broken
```

The above commands may resolve the issue. If not, try reinstalling the postfix after purging the old one.
Purge the old one

```
sudo apt remove --purge postfix
```

Clean the old and unnecessary packages using the command

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
```

Update and upgrade the packages

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Reinstall the package

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Comment: please, check my update question, it not working.